# How can a value in a array be read / written in LLVM IR using the c api?

Tags: c, llvm-ir

Given the code c

```
int foo(int *array)
{
    return array[2];
}
```

I can view the IR by running `clang file.c -O1 -S -emit-llvm -o -` and get

```
define dso_local i32 @foo(i32* nocapture readonly %0) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %0, i64 2
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4, !tbaa !4
  ret i32 %3
}
```

When working using the c-api of LLVM I wrote the following code

```
#include <llvm-c/Analysis.h>
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
    LLVMModuleRef module = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("test");
    LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();
    LLVMTypeRef llvm_fn_type = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMInt32Type(), (LLVMTypeRef[]){LLVMPointerType(LLVMInt32Type(), 0)}, 1, false);
    LLVMValueRef fn = LLVMAddFunction(module, "fn", llvm_fn_type);
    LLVMBasicBlockRef entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(fn, "entry");
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);
    LLVMValueRef arg = LLVMGetParam(fn, 0);
    LLVMValueRef index_2 = LLVMBuildStructGEP(builder, arg, 2, ""); // <---- crashes
    LLVMValueRef index_2_val = LLVMBuildLoad(builder, index_2, "");
    LLVMBuildRet(builder, index_1_val);
    return 0;
}
```

When running LLVMBuildStructGEP, the code crashes.

What is the proper why to create the above IR?

Answer (score 0):

Since the argument type isn't a struct, LLVMBuildStructGEP cannot work here

Replacing the call to `LLVMBuildStructGEP` by `LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP` with `{0, 2}` as the indices should work

edit:
or you can use `LLVMBuildGEP` with `{2}` as the indices, I might be wrong about the indices since its been a while since I used the GEP instruction, but this [link](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html) should be useful

Answer (score 0):

So after a while of playing around, I realised that it ends up that functions like `LLVMBuildStructGEP` and `LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP` add an extra dereference that is not needed. By using `LLVMBuildGEP` I can get the address.

```
LLVMValueRef index_2 = LLVMBuildGEP(builder, arg,
            (LLVMValueRef[]){LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32Type(), 2, false)},
            1, "");
```